# Sharing data in local thread python in different threads

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have stored request_id in local thread python, this thread creates three more threads which won't have access to request_id. How can I share or send request_id info from one thread local to another.

Answer (score 0):

Python methods of data sharing between threads and processes:

- [Multithreading and data sharing in python](https://programming.vip/docs/multithreading-and-data-sharing-in-python.html)
- [Handling and Sharing Data Between Threads](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/handling-and-sharing-data-between-threads/)